# Efficiently save user session in Rails using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to learn Rails and have created User model using devise but just using Rails an API. I have added custom validations on the controller and it works fine. The user is able to login when posting data from the front-end. But, the problem is that the browser doesn't store the session anywhere. Hence, the session will be considered new every-time a page is reloaded. I am wondering if devise has an in-built functionality which would create session and store in cookie or local storage.

```
class API::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(user_params[:email])
    if @user && @user.valid_password?(user_params[:password])
      sign_in :user, @user
      render json: @user
    elsif @user && not(@user.valid_password?(user_params[:password]))
      invalid_attempt
    else
      no_user
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @message = "signed out"
    sign_out(@user)
    render json: @message
  end

  private

  def no_user
    render json: {error: "An account with this email doesn't exist. Please create a new one"}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end

  def invalid_attempt
    render json: { error: "Your password isn't correct" }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
  end
end
```